# Ember data - get first of collection

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Okay, it's shocking how poorly documented this is and that I cannot find an answer quickly.

How to I get the first object of a collection in ember?

This is the collection:

```
this.store.query('review', { order_id: params.id })
```

I want the first record and only the first record (not as a collection) to use in my template.

None of these work:

```
// First attempt
this.store.query('review', { order_id: params.id })[0];
// Second attempt
this.store.query('review', { order_id: params.id }).get('firstObject');

// Third attempt
var r;
this.store.query('review', { order_id: params.id }).then(function(results) {
  r = results.get('firstObject');
});
```

Comment: You are mistaking [Ember.Enumerable](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html) with [DS.Model](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html), you are already fetching all of the records you can just use `.firstObject` in the template.

Comment: It doesn't work @Kitler

Comment: What errors do you get? How are you setting it? How are you calling it in the template? Does the backend return anything?.... add the relevant code and a [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com) if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If say you have a router, and  you define your model function as such:

```
model: function(){
  return this.store.query('review', {order_id: params.id}).then(function(results) {
    return results.get('firstObject');
  });
}
```

Then in your template:

```
{{model}}
```

Does it not work?